# How To Create an unsecured layout page in SharePoint that can be accessed by anonmyous (guest) users

Tags: sharepoint, anonymous, applicationpage

I'm trying to do something that should be really simple.

I have created a SharePoint Application page that is deployed into the _layouts folder.  This page uses a custom code behind that inherits from Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.

I have the application page referencing a master page that can be best described as Minimal Master Page (it has all of the basic SharePoint content placeholders and that is about it).

But when I try to access the page using a Web Application that is configured to allow anonmyous access I still get prompted to login to the page.  I've checked permissions on the Master Page Gallery and Style Gallery.  These are configured to allow anonmyous access.

I've never created a Application Page that can be accessed by anonmyous account, but it should be doable.

Any ideas for troubleshooting this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer to my problem [here](http://experimentsincode.com/blog/post/sharepoint-unsecured-application-page)

In a nutt-shell you have to override the AllowAnonymousAccess property and return true.  Once I did that the Page works as expected.

```
protected override bool AllowAnonymousAccess
{   
      get{   
             return true;   
         }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Nice easy answer to my 'challenge'